# Context menu in OS X in icon view

Tags: macos, contextmenu, finder

I am trying to add context menu item to OSX Finder in Snow Leopard and Lion. I was able to find the method Finder calls when it is in File View. The method is addViewSpecificStuffToMenu. I was not able to find the related method in icon view mode. Does anyone know what is the method I should hack ?

amit

Comment: yes I will. soon i will post full solution description

Comment: Please do. I am stuck at (sounds like) EXACTLY the same place. Most of my work is done in menuNeedsUpdate:, however.

Comment: I promise, once my code will work :-)

Comment: actually, addViewSpecificStuffToMenu: works for me in the icon view. I am having problems now obtaining information about the thing that has been right-clicked. Still looking forward to your writeup.

Comment: can you please give more information about what is your problem ? It will help me to provide an useful answer.

Comment: Well, oddly enough, the `addViewSpecificStuffToMenu` method swizzle works for me in all finder views... but I'm using the services API to get an `NSURL` of the item that has been right-clicked. That `NSURL` isn't available at the time `addViewSpecificStuffToMenu` is called. It IS available if I swizzle `NSMenu`'s `popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:`. But that method only works for file view, not for icon views.

Comment: Nevermind! I got the services API stuff to work all the time, and to fix the problem of when the `NSURL` is available, I just retain a reference to the menu passed into `addViewSpecificStuffToMenu` and operate on it again when my `NSURL` becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

The `addViewSpecificStuffToMenu` method works for me in all the related finder views.